# Take 1st row of CSV and turn it into a default value in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a fussy file export that basically creates a CSV with an odd format like:

```
filename, date
header1, header2, header3, header4
value1, value2, value3, value4
value5, value6, value7, value8
```

I'm trying to take that 'date' field from the first row and create a 5th column with that value as the default value.

I then want to delete that first row entirely. Deleting the row isn't the issue, I just can't think of a way of selecting that date value and turning it into a new column.

Comment: _I just can't think of a way of selecting that date value and turning it into a new column._ Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service, nor is it an alternative to guides or documentation, do you have a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Yeh, the question is how to individually select a cell and use that to create a column. I'm giving background. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the csv library to read like so:

```
import csv

with open('path_to_file_', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)

    # first get the date
    first_line = next(reader)
    date = first_line[1]

    # read the rest and add the date to every line
    lines = [l.append(date) for l in list(reader)]
```